# Why weak law of large number still alive?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I know the difference between WLLN and SLLN in terms of a convergence type. Then, as revealed in any statistical textbook saying sufficient conditions to two theorems are the same, I think that we do not need WLLN anymore. I also know that there is some example for which WLLN holds but SLLN not. Then, From this examples we would have needed to establish another conditions only needed for SLLN, still I could not find any explanations for this.

Is there anyone to explain difference between WLLN and SLLN in terms of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Sufficient conditions needn't be *minimally sufficient* conditions. Usually, the minimally sufficient conditions for an SLLN to hold are stronger than those under which a corresponding WLLN holds. Depending on the application at hand, it may not be appropriate to proceed as if the conditions for a strong law were satisfied; nevertheless, useful results may be obtained if the conditions for a weak law are satisfied.

Comment: In statistics or econometrics people care consistency of estimators and consistency is defined through convergence in probability. Estimators are often functions of some sample averages. Usually then it is enough to guarantee conditions for a WLLN (e.g., Chebyshev's WLLN) to prove consistency of estimators.

Comment: SLLN is harder to prove in general than WLLN if all you have is iid with finite expectation. Examples [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Differences_between_the_weak_law_and_the_strong_law) where WLLN applies and SLLN does not (no finite absolute expectation): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609954/2958 with $\mathbb P\left(X_i=\frac{(-2)^n}{n} \right)=\frac1{2^n}$ over positive integer $n$ and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205564/2958 with $Y_i$ being exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $1$ and $X_i= \dfrac{\sin(Y_i) e^{Y_i}}{Y_i}$

Answer (score 15):

**Feller's WLLN** says $X_n$ are i.i.d and let $S_n=\sum X_i$. Then $\exists C_n$(finite) such that
$$\frac{S_n-C_n}{n}\overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \hspace{10pt} \iff nP({X_1}>n)\rightarrow 0$$
In such a case $\frac{C_n}{n}=E(X_1I\{|X_1|\leq n\})+o(1)$.

**Kolmogorov's SLLN** says $X_n$ are i.i.d and let $S_n=\sum X_i$.Then
$$\frac{S_n}{n}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} c \hspace{10pt}\text{for some finite c}\hspace{10pt}\iff X_1\in L_1$$
In such a case necessarily $c=E(X_1)$.

**Result:** $X\in L_p \Rightarrow n^pP(|X_1|>n^{1/p})\rightarrow 0$. But the otherway IS NOT TRUE!

Thus $X_1\in L_1$ means we can apply SLLN and WLLN both. The following example depicts WLLN holds but not SLLN

Let $X_n$ i.i.d with density $f(x)=\frac{c}{x^2\log{|x|}} I\{|x|>e\}$. Show that $E(X^{+})=\infty=E(X^{-})$ implying $E(X)$ does not exist. We can not apply SLLN. But it's not hard to show $nP(|X_1|>n)=o(1)$. Hence by WLLN we've
$$\frac{S_n}{n} -E(X_1I\{|X_1|\leq n\})\overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$$
Since $X_1$ is symmetric the above expectation is $0$, i.e. $\frac{S_n}{n}\overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$.

In this example you can also show 
$$\limsup \frac{S_n}{n}=\infty \hspace{10pt}\text{and}\hspace{10pt}\liminf \frac{S_n}{n}=-\infty\hspace{3pt}\text{almost surely}$$

Thus it's clearly false that $\frac{S_n}{n}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0$.

Comment: Thanks! In your example, does that mean even if $X\notin L_1,$ WLLN can hold?

Comment: +1. This (already very) nice answer would be quite complete if, to the OP's benefit, a reference to some canonical text was added.

Comment: @kurtkim Yes. There are many good books to read among which as a basic graduate course I like 'Probability Theory: A Graduste Course' by Allan Gut (Chapter 6 for laws of large numbers). Feel free to mention your favourite treatises.

Comment: @Saty Nice answer. By the way, in the last part, I am curious how to show $\limsup \frac{S_n}{n} = \infty$

Comment: @Saty Can you give a reference on Feller's WLLN, I'm quite curious on the proof of this theorem.

Comment: @Schrödinger'sCat See Durrett _Probability: Theory and Examples_, Fourth Edition, Theorem 2.2.7, p.60.