# An interesting corollary on convergence in probability

Tags: probability

I recently think of a corollary concerning convergence in probability. Say

> $X_i$, i.i.d random variables and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, if
>
> $$S_n / n \to 0 \quad \text{in probability}.$$
>
> Does this imply that $n\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>n)\to 0$ ?

The reason this problem attracts me is that we know that $S_n/n$ converges a.s. implies convergence in probability. Also $S_n/n$ a.s. convergence is equivalent with $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$ by SLLN, and $\mathbb{E}|X|<\infty$, implies $n\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)\to 0$. Since

$$n\mathbb{P}(|X|>n)\leq \int_{|X|>n}|X| d\mathbb{P}\to 0.$$

But any of the two conditions in this problem does not necessarily imply $S_n/n$ converges almost surely. So the problem could be summarized that if condition A implies condition B and condition A also implies condition C. Which one is stronger, B or C?

Comment: The answer to your first question is positive. This is Feller's weak law of large numbers, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422777/why-weak-law-of-large-number-still-alive. Concerning another question, it is not clear what are A, B and C.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks, Actually it already solved my problem.